# PHP HTTP Post Response

Tags: php

```
//echo $vars1;
$curl = curl_init('http://api.sms.com/api/v2/sendsms/plain?');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vars1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($curl);

$Status =$result;
```

Please I need to get the value of the HTTP response above into a PHP variable but I kept on getting a string variable. When I use var_dump($result); this is what I got

```
<result>
 <status>0</status><messageid>032120313205357007</messageid><destination>23348787878555</destination>
</result>'
```

Can any one help me on how to get the individual element into a PHP variable?

Comment: No, I don't understand exactly what you want. Please give us the desired output example.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The desire output is a number that is either numeric number which can be a negative or positive integer. it is a respose from an sms server, if the respose is greater greater than 1 (>1) then the is no error but if it is less the 1 then it is an error such as -1.

Answer (score 1):

To parse the result and extract the status element, you can use [simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php)

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
$status = $xml->xpath('/result/status');
echo $status[0];
```

You can also iterate over the XML element

```
foreach ($xml as $element => $text) {
    echo "$element: $text\n";
}
```

Comment: when i used var_dump($result) this is what i got <result>
 <status>0</status><messageid>032120313205357007</messageid><destination>23348787878555</destination>
</result>'. I need to parse the value of the xml elemete "status" into a variable. THIS IS MY PROBLEM. PLEASE HELP ALL!

Comment: Olaf Dietsche, thanks for your response. it is 100% of what I want to do. Have a good day